# How to resolve Office 365 connection error with sharepoint online credentials

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365

Currently i am trying to connect to office 365 sharepoint via my my application and used below approach so i can perform further operations after connecting like listing, document upload etc.

```
        static string siteUrl = "https://<<Site URL>>";
        static string userName = "xxxxxxxx";
        static string password = "xxxxxxxxx";

        public async static void Uploadfiles()
        {
            try
            {
                ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
                SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
                password.ToList().ForEach(secureString.AppendChar);
                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, secureString);
                Web web = ctx.Web;
                Site site = ctx.Site;
                ctx.Load(site);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(site.Url.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred : " + ex.Message);
                System.Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

But when it executes query it throws below error:

```
Cannot contact web site 'https://<<Site Url>>/' or the web site does not support SharePoint Online credentials. The response status code is 'Unauthorized'. The response headers are 'X-SharePointHealthScore=1, X-MSDAVEXT_Error=917656; Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically., SPRequestGuid=0e6f41a0-90f3-1000-2182-78f5074383d4, request-id=0e6f41a0-90f3-1000-2182-78f5074383d4, MS-CV=oEFvDvOQABAhgnj1B0OD1A.0, Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=31536000, SPRequestDuration=15, SPIisLatency=0, MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices=16.0.0.22504, X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff, X-MS-InvokeApp=1; RequireReadOnly, X-Cache=CONFIG_NOCACHE, X-MSEdge-Ref=Ref A: 45D6DA1299E1407E9FD61C019494216D Ref B: BL2EDGE2116 Ref C: 2022-05-27T09:06:08Z, Content-Length=0, Content-Type=text/plain; charset=utf-8, Date=Fri, 27 May 2022 09:06:08 GMT, P3P=CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI", X-Powered-By=ASP.NET'.
```

Any idea do i need to configure anything at site level or i am missing anything in my approach.

Answer (score 0):

SharepointOnlineCredentials uses legacy authentication that is now by default disabled on the tenants. If you have tenant admin rights, you could enable it if you do not care about the security issue.
Otherwise, you need to use OAUTH token authentication, take a look at the MSAL or PNP Framework libraries (Authentication Manager class).